# Write from databricks in storage account using Service Principal token

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, service-principal

I know how to write from databricks using storage account access key.

```
spark.conf.set(
  "fs.azure.account.key.MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net",
  "XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXx")

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo")],["id", "label"])

df.write.format("delta").save("wasbs://MyContainer@MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/HERE")
```

Now I want to do the same using Servie Principal.

I found this code to generate a valid SP token:

```
client_id = "AXAXAXAX"
secret_id = "YNTHBRGEZFGTYUI"
storage_account_url = "https://MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/"

token_credential = ClientSecretCredential(TENANT_ID, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
```

How can I pass it to my spark session in order to access the desired storage account.
My SPN is already contributer on desired storage account MyStorageAccount.

**EDIT:**

After further searching, I found the [following tuto](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/synapse-analytics), so I wrote the same code:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id", client_id)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret", secret_id)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/token")

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo")],["id", "label"])

df.write.format("delta").save("wasbs://MyContainer@MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/HERE")
```

But I am having the following error:

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: 
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container MyContainerin account MyStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can&#39;t create it using anoynomous credentials, and no credentials found for them in the configuration.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial you linked is for Azure Synapse.

Databricks allows you to mount Blob Storage using account key or SAS ->[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-storage#access-azure-blob-storage-using-the-dataframe-api).

You can access Datalake storage using OAuth ->[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#access-adls-gen2-directly). So if you are able to convert your storage account (ie. enable hierarchical namespace) then you'll be able to use it.

Comment: convert my storage account ? Can you explain more please ?

Comment: You can convert an existing storage account from Blob Storage to Datalake Storage Gen2. Here are the [considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/upgrade-to-data-lake-storage-gen2) and [exact steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/upgrade-to-data-lake-storage-gen2-how-to?tabs=azure-portal).